# Conditional probability of measured distribution given intrinsic distribution

Tags: conditional-probability, derived-distributions

I have a population whose property $X$ that is distributed according to its intrinsic distribution $P$, $ \sim P(X)$.  I make a measurement of $X$ on this population and I get that $var \sim Q(X)$ with $P \neq Q$ due to measurement errors. How do I compute the probability that intrinsically $A < X <B$ being that instead I am measuring $C<X<D$ ?
 I thought about using the definition of conditional probability, 
$Prob( A<X<B; intrinsic | C<X<D; measured) = \frac{Prob ( (A<X<B; intrinsic) \ \cap \ (C<X<D; measured)) }{  Prob (C<X<D; measured)}$
but I don't know how to compute the numerator in this case.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Edit:  for example suppose X is a physical property like blood pressure.  We know the measured blood pressure of a sample of patients which is convolved with the intrinsic error of the measurement (guassian standard deviation). That is if for instance $P(X)= \delta(X)$ then $Q(X)=\mathcal{N}(X; \mu, \sigma)$.

Comment: A lot--perhaps everything--hinges on exactly how you "get" that "$\text{var}\sim Q(\text{var})$."  Could you edit your question to provide that information? BTW, "var" is a confusing name to use for a general property, given that it is almost universally used for the *variance* of a random variable or distribution.  It would be better to change it.  Why not the traditional "$X$"?

Comment: so what you are asking is how do you adjust A and B to reflect the fact measurement error is now introduced? Have you separately quantified your measurement error? What pieces of information will you have available?

Comment: No I'm asking how likely it is that I measure C<X<D whereas actually it is A<X<B (or the other way around). A, B, C and D are just some input numbers.